# How to avoid matrix autoscale?

Tags: android, matrix

view width: 480;
view height: 720;

bitmapWidth: 2592;
bitmapHeight: 1552;

```
setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix = new Matrix();
setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

in fact bitmap resizes to 1726 that is unsuitable to me because I need to show and make manipulate (translate, zoom, rotate) extending on it's original size.

**Update:**

I even tried to use this init code, but it not helped me:

```
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
matrix.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using setImageBitmap instead of setImageURI

Answer (score 0):

When using matrix, you should [setScale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setScale(float,%20float)) to desired ratio. `setScale(1,1)` will display image as is, but it may not fit the screen.
In order to fit the image to View size, you can use either other scale type on the ImageView (for example, FIT_XY), or apply [setRectToRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit)) to the matrix.

Comment: a tried to setScale(1,1), but my image is still 1726 width instead of 1592

Comment: where do you fetch image from? /res/drawable? if yes, then it may be re-scaled to match device density. width 1592 or 2592? error in question?

Comment: from sd card, image with size 1980x1080 displayed as is